# In ACM in-text citations, should the first citation to a given source include anything except a number enclosed in brackets?

Tags: citation-style

For example, suppose I am citing Dr. John Doe's *Pie Are Round, Pi Are Not Square: Digitally Representing Double Entendres from Natural Languages* for the first time in my paper.  Which of the following would be acceptable?

> A particularly useful algorithm for ranking the corniness of natural-language jokes may be found in [3], where...

> Doe [3] presents a particularly useful algorithm for ranking the corniness of natural-language jokes, where...

> In his groundbreaking *Pie Are Round, Pi Are Not Square: Digitally Representing Double Entendres from Natural Languages*, Doe [3] presents a particularly useful algorithm for ranking the corniness of natural-language jokes, where...

Thank you...